# How do I add numbers in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to work on a problem.

---

If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.

### Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

I have most of this done. However, I cant get the numbers to add up in the array. Here is the code I have so far

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var counter;
        for (counter = 0; counter < 1001; counter++) {
            if (counter % 3 == 0 || counter % 5 == 0) {
                var arrayNumbers = [];
                arrayNumbers.push(counter);


            }
        }

        var total = 0;
        $.each(arrayNumbers, function () {
            total += this;
        });

        console.log(total);
    });
</script>
```

The console logs this as 1000

I think what is wrng is the scope of my variables. How can I fix this?

Comment: declare the *arrayNumbers* array outside the for loop

Comment: Why bother with the array at all? Just sum them as you go along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create you `arrayNumbers` outside the `for loop`, or it will be **disposed and overriden** in each loop.

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var counter;
        var arrayNumbers = [];
        for (counter = 0; counter < 1001; counter++) {
            if (counter % 3 == 0 || counter % 5 == 0) {
                arrayNumbers.push(counter);
            }
        }

        var total = 0;
        $.each(arrayNumbers, function () {
            total += this;
        });

        console.log(total);
    });
</script>
```

---

I did not want to mess up your algorithm, but I recommend you to use a **counter** variable for this exercise.

You should increment the counter by each multiple you find, and the final value of the counter would be the **sum of all the multiples**

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var counter = 0;
        var number;

        for (number = 0; number < 1001; number++) {
            if (number % 3 == 0 || number % 5 == 0) {
                counter += number;
            }
        }

        console.log(counter);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @Aravind and why did you not post the answer instead of a comment? ;p

Comment: Lol! Not a valuable question to answer. Anyways not a problem

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved without array, by using loop only ones.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var counter;
        var result;
        for (counter = 0; counter < 1001; counter++) {
            if (counter % 3 == 0 || counter % 5 == 0) {
               result+=counter;
            }
         console.log(result);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without any array or jQuery:

```
var counter, total=0;
for (counter = 0; counter <= 1000; counter++) {
    if (counter % 3 == 0 || counter % 5 == 0) {
        total += counter;
    }
}
console.log(total);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/WuNJ5/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do that summation in the for loop? kinda like this:

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter;
    var total= 0;
    for (counter = 0; counter < 1001; counter++) {
        if (counter % 3 == 0 || counter % 5 == 0) {
            var arrayNumbers = [];
            arrayNumbers.push(counter);
            total += counter;

        }
    }
    console.log(total);
});
```